# How to use a full text index via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to use a full text index with entity framework without having to call a stored procedure. I couldnt find any code for this. Does anyone know of any nuget packages that provide this functionality if it doesnt exist?

Comment: SQL queries directly support full text indexes using the `contains()` function.

Comment: https://www.bricelam.net/2020/08/08/mssql-freetext-and-efcore.html